# Can't accept pop-up for "block" or "allow" alerts in android chrome

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

I have Moto G6 play Oreo 8.0.0 and I can't reply to alerts like approving access to the microphone.

Things I've tried:

- rotating the phone to Landscape
- killed the Display Over Other Apps for twilight

Edit:

I can close a JS alert popup. 
And there's no problem on android FF.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've allowed pop-ups (pop-ups from some sites may be blocked).
You can do this by going to Settings > Site settings > Pop-ups and redirects. Then turn "pop-ups and redirects" on.

Comment: I've allowed it but it didn't solve the problem